# Unable to deserialise via mixin

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Attached is my json. I am receiving this from an endpoint. I have the object type in my consuming app. the object contains; success, message and loggedInMember (which is an object).  In the json, the `feeClasses` contains a lot of fields and objects etc which is why i have not included the whole json. I am only interested in the `success` and `message` fields.

```
{
    "header":{
    "messageId":null,
            "receivedTimestamp":1611246394839,
            "replyTo":null,
            "redelivered":false,
            "originator":null
},
    "internalId":null,
        "auditPoints":[

],
        "success":true,
        "message":"",
        "loggedInMember":{
            "feeClasses":{
...CONTAINS A LOT OF FIELDS...
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to map this response to the object type, hence essentially leaving `loggedInMembers` null. This is my test I am trying to run:

```
   public void test() throws JsonProcessingException
   {
      //String json = "{\"header\":{\"messageId\":null,\"bucketNumber\":null,\"senderSubId\":null,\"senderLocationId\":null,\"onBehalfOfCompId\":null,\"onBehalfOfSubId\":null,\"onBehalfOfLocationId\":null,\"correlationId\":null,\"receivedTimestamp\":1611246394839,\"replyTo\":null,\"redelivered\":false,\"originator\":null},\"internalId\":null,\"auditPoints\":[],\"success\":true,\"message\":\"\",\"loggedInMember\":{\"memberLoginName\":\"BMARTINTEST\",\"memberId\":\"201901241246290000036402D\",\"settlementAccountIds\":[\"201901241246290000036491D\"],\"parentMemberId\":\"1\",\"firmId\":\"990\",\"memberType\":\"INDIVIDUAL\",\"memberAccountType\":\"PROD\",\"password\":\"D1208B304FD7AA6187690A389A5040C1D9B07643\",\"feeClasses\":{\"byId\":{\"201902120947520000559606D\":{\"memberLoginName\":\"BMARTINTEST\",\"feeClassId\":\"201508041827550000942152D\",\"memberFeeClassId\":\"201902120947520000559606D\",\"allocatedDate\":{\"year\":2019,\"month\":2,\"day\":12,\"timeMillis\":1549929600000},\"firstUsedForTradeDate\":{\"year\":2019,\"month\":2,\"day\":12,\"timeMillis\":1549929600000},\"firstUsedForSettlementDate\":null,\"usableFromDate\":{\"year\":2019,\"month\":2,\"day\":12,\"timeMillis\":1549929600000},\"usableToDate\":{\"year\":2019,\"month\":2,\"day\":19,\"timeMillis\":1550534400000},\"usableToTimestamp\":1550613600000,\"usableBusinessDaysAllocated\":6,\"usableBusinessDaysRemaining\":0,\"narrative\":\"Bonus assigned to member at first-time funding of amount 4000.00 : Set expiration date/time\",\"disabled\":false,\"usableForTrade\":true,\"usableForSettlement\":true},\"202001290940390000868824D\":{\"memberLoginName\":\"BMARTINTEST\",\"feeClassId\":\"202001290940340000776406D\",\"memberFeeClassId\":\"202001290940390000868824D\",\"allocatedDate\":{\"year\":2020,\"month\":1,\"day\":29,\"timeMillis\":1580256000000},\"firstUsedForTradeDate\":null,\"firstUsedForSettlementDate\":null,\"usableFromDate\":{\"year\":2020,\"month\":1,\"day\":6,\"timeMillis\":1578268800000},\"usableToDate\":{\"year\":2020,\"month\":2,\"day\":27,\"timeMillis\":1582761600000},\"usableToTimestamp\":1582840800000,\"usableBusinessDaysAllocated\":0,\"usableBusinessDaysRemaining\":0,\"narrative\":\"Added NO_FEES_CLASS\",\"disabled\":false,\"usableForTrade\":true,\"usableForSettlement\":true},\"201901241246290000036417D\":{\"memberLoginName\":\"BMARTINTEST\",\"feeClassId\":\"201508041736360000943781D\",\"memberFeeClassId\":\"201901241246290000036417D\",\"allocatedDate\":{\"year\":2019,\"month\":1,\"day\":24,\"timeMillis\":1548288000000},\"firstUsedForTradeDate\":null,\"firstUsedForSettlementDate\":null,\"usableFromDate\":{\"year\":2019,\"month\":1,\"day\":24,\"timeMillis\":1548288000000},\"usableToDate\":null,\"usableToTimestamp\":null,\"usableBusinessDaysAllocated\":0,\"usableBusinessDaysRemaining\":0,\"narrative\":null,\"disabled\":false,\"usableForTrade\":true,\"usableForSettlement\":true}},\"empty\":false},\"legalName\":\"Martin Birch\",\"taxId\":\"345335454\",\"taxCountryId\":\"US\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"lastTradeId\":null,\"introducingBrokerMemberId\":null,\"introducingBrokerMemberName\":null,\"introducingBrokerMemberCode\":null,\"clearedByMemberId\":\"SECOND_TEST\",\"clearedByMemberLoginName\":null,\"memberProblems\":[],\"emailNotificationEnabled\":true,\"rtafLevelId\":0,\"rtafAmount\":0,\"maxNumberOfPositionAccounts\":1,\"ciciIdentifier\":null,\"traderRequired\":false,\"interestClass\":\"INDIVIDUAL\",\"memberCreatedDate\":1548333989000,\"parentMemberLoginNames\":[\"NADEX.COM\",\"NADEX\"],\"demoStartDate\":null,\"demoEndDate\":null,\"clientIdMaxLimit\":null,\"memberAccountApplicationFieldData\":null,\"rank\":0,\"uuid\":\"201901241246290000036395D\",\"referrerId\":\"raf4qam5h00s36d\",\"testMember\":false},\"allReplyToSource\":[],\"sendToOriginatorOnly\":false}";
String json = "{\n" +
              "   \"header\":{\n" +
              "      \"messageId\":null,\n" +
              "      \"receivedTimestamp\":1611246394839,\n" +
              "      \"replyTo\":null,\n" +
              "      \"redelivered\":false,\n" +
              "      \"originator\":null\n" +
              "   },\n" +
              "   \"internalId\":null,\n" +
              "   \"auditPoints\":[\n" +
              "      \n" +
              "   ],\n" +
              "   \"success\":true,\n" +
              "   \"message\":\"\",\n" +
              "   \"loggedInMember\":{\n" +
              "      \"feeClasses\":{\n" +
              "         \n" +
              "      }\n" +
              "   }\n" +
              "}";
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
      objectMapper.addMixIn(LogonResponseMessage.class, LogonResponseMixin.class);

      LogonResponseMessage responseMessage = objectMapper.readValue(json, LogonResponseMessage.class);

      System.out.println(responseMessage);
   }
```

My mixin:

```
public abstract class LogonResponseMixin
{
   LogonResponseMixin(@JsonProperty("success") boolean success, @JsonProperty("message") String message){};

   @JsonIgnore
   abstract Member loggedInMember();

   @JsonIgnore
   abstract MemberFeeClasses feeClasses();

   @JsonIgnore
   abstract Header header();
}
```

I am getting the following error: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of domain.xyz.MemberFeeClasses (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)`

Am i creating the mixin wrong? I have asked in a previous question and using mixin was the general consensus but it doesn't seem to play ball with me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why MemberFeeClasses cannot be constructed is the same as your initial problem, just add a mixin for all classes

See the example below:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

  //------------------------------------------------//
  //          PART 1 - MAIN TEST METHOD
  //------------------------------------------------//
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String json = "{\n" +
        "   \"header\":{" +
        "   },\n" +
        "   \"success\":true,\n" +
        "   \"message\":\"\",\n" +
        "   \"loggedInMember\":{\n" +
        "      \"feeClasses\":{\n" +
        "         \"amount\": \"20\"\n" +
        "      }\n" +
        "   }\n" +
        "}";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    objectMapper.addMixIn(LogonResponseMessage.class, LogonResponseMixin.class);
    objectMapper.addMixIn(Member.class, MemberMixin.class);
    objectMapper.addMixIn(MemberFee.class, MemberFeeMixin.class);

    LogonResponseMessage responseMessage = objectMapper.readValue(json, LogonResponseMessage.class);

    System.out.println(responseMessage.loggedInMember.feeClasses.amount);
  }

  //------------------------------------------------//
  //          PART 2 - CREATOR MIXIN
  //------------------------------------------------//
  static abstract class LogonResponseMixin {
    LogonResponseMixin(@JsonProperty("success") boolean success,
                       @JsonProperty("message") String message,
                       @JsonProperty("header") Header header,
                       @JsonProperty("loggedInMember") Member member) {
    }
  }

  static abstract class MemberMixin {
    MemberMixin(@JsonProperty("feeClasses") MemberFee feeClasses) {
    }
  }

  static abstract class MemberFeeMixin {
    @JsonCreator
    MemberFeeMixin(@JsonProperty("amount") String amount) {
    }
  }

  //------------------------------------------------//
  //          PART 3 - EXAMPLE CLASS DEFINITION
  //------------------------------------------------//
  static class Header {
  }

  @Getter
  @Setter
  static class Member {
    private MemberFee feeClasses;

    public Member(MemberFee feeClasses) {
      this.feeClasses = feeClasses;
    }
  }

  @Getter
  @Setter
  static class MemberFee {
    private String amount;
    public MemberFee(String amount) {
      this.amount = amount;
    }
  }

  @Getter
  @Setter
  static class LogonResponseMessage {
    private boolean success;
    private String message;
    private Header header;
    private Member loggedInMember;

    public LogonResponseMessage(boolean success, String message, Header header, Member member) {
      this.success = success;
      this.message = message;
      this.header = header;
      this.loggedInMember = member;
    }
  }
}
```